# Python: BeautifulSoup extract string between div tag by its class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import urllib, urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
url='http://www.amazon.in/product-reviews/B00CE2LUKQ/ref=cm_cr_pr_top_link_1?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=0&sortBy=bySubmissionDateDescending'
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
rows =soup.find_all('div',attrs={"class" : "reviewText"})
print rows
```

This code is used to extract the reviews from the website. I need **only** the text  - but I get them with the div tags.

I need help regarding how the text alone gets extracted.  I require the text alone-between the div class tags.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
for row in soup.find_all('div',attrs={"class" : "reviewText"}):
    print row.text
```

or:

```
[row.text for row in rows]
```