# Python Regular expression match with newlines

Tags: python, regex

I am trying a regex match with no luck..  I want to match against this

```
<div class="row">
            Published
        September 17th 2013
         by Smashwords

      </div>
```

This is my regex

```
re.search(r"""<div class="row">\n Published\n (.*) (.*) (.*)\n by (.*)\n </div>""", page2, re.DOTALL|re.M)
```

I wanted to match the date and the Smashwords.. No luck so far... Any idea?

Comment: I guess you are trying some web scraping. What exactly are you aiming for? Do you want to extract the date? or the whole `<div>` ?

Comment: Just the date and Publisher name..

Answer (score 2):

You need to consider about the whitespaces in your regexp pattern. Here's a working pattern:

```
<div class="row">\n\s+Published\n\s+(\S*) (.*) (.*)\n\s+by (\S*)\n\s+</div>
(changes:)         ^^^           ^^^ ^^              ^^^    ^^    ^^^
```

It will give the result `('September', '17th', '2013', 'Smashwords')`

Comment: Adding that cause my script to freeze at that line

Comment: Thanks but still get the script stuck...  I copied your text but nothin

Comment: @maurizioderuggiero just copy the first line of the regex in my answer... see [the paste](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23904206/)

Comment: I did..  I checked twice and is the same but script get stuck maybe is problem on my end..

Comment: Ok..  It takes forever to give me results but it actually works..  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use BeautifulSoup to parse HTML code may be a better choice.

```
import bs4

html = '''<div class="row">
            Published
        September 17th 2013
         by Smashwords

      </div>'''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
#--------This is acuture code, just one line-------#
soup.get_text(strip=True).split('\n        ')
```

out:

```
['Published', 'September 17th 2013', ' by Smashwords']
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex captures the date and the Smashwords in groups 1, 2, 3 and 4 respectively:

```
import re
x =re.match(r'<div class="row">\n[ ]+Published\n\s+([A-Za-z]+) ([A-Za-z0-9]+) ([0-9]+)\n\s+by ([A-Za-z0-9]+)\n\n\s+</div>', data, re.DOTALL|re.M)
print(x.group(1))
```

The main problem with your script was the whitespaces were not considered.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to use pure regex for that. (As per your comment)

You can get the text inside `div` using `Beautifulsoup`.
Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21290018/4954434

Now use `[a-z,A-Z]*\s([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])th\s[0-9]{4}` to find date.
Then find publisher assuming it to be the combination of all words after "by".

Assuming `a = "text inside <div>"`,

```
b=a.split()
s = ''
for w in reversed(b):
    if w == 'by':
        break
    else:
        s = w + ' ' + s
```

will fetch you the publisher.