# Python - Extracting name of href hyperlink

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

I'm using Python to extract data from a webpage. The webpage has many anchor tags that have href attributes.

For example:

```
<a class="identifier" href="/ICD10CM/Codes/A00-B99/A15-A19/A18-/A18.17">A18.17</a>
```

I am able to extract these specific tags by using

for x in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(x)

However, I only want to extract the *name* of the link (A18.17 in the example). How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print x.text
```

There is a similar question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289966/python-beautifulsoup-extract-string-between-div-tag-by-its-class) and [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Advanced%20Topics) should help.